# How to write a unix filter that outputs only a line every N lines

Tags: unix, shell, scripting, awk

Suppose to feed the filter standard input with these line:

```
line 1 
line 2
line 3
line 4 
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
```

It would be nicer if someone tell me how to write a script that prints only every 4 lines, in the case of the example input above:

```
line 1
line 5
line 9
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$ yes | cat -n | head -10 | awk 'NR % 4 == 1'
     1  y
     5  y
     9  y
```

That is, your answer is "`awk 'NR % 4 == 1'`".

Comment: It's refreshing that someone is aware of the default action in awk.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{ if ((NR-1) %4 ==0) print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR%4 == 1 {print}'</etc/hosts
```

Replace 4 by whatever value you want of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -ne '1~4p’
```

(GNU `sed`. Not tested on OSX, etc.)